# Equivalent conditions for a 2-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I am reading A Textbook of Graph Theory by Balakrishnan and Ranganathan. I believe there is a problem with the following exercises.

> Exercise 3.7 (a) Show that a graph $G$ with at least three vertices is 2-connected if
> and only if any vertex and any edge of $G$ lie on a common cycle of $G$.
> (b) Show that a graph $G$ with at least three vertices is 2-connected if and only if
> any two edges of $G$ lie on a common cycle.

For a graph with at least three vertices, the definition of 2-connected can be: 'any two vertices lie on a common cycle'.

I don't think the converse direction of either of these statements is true. My counterexample is the graph of just three isolated vertices and no edges. Can somebody confirm this?

I think it would suffice to include the assumption that $G$ is connected for the converse statements to hold.

Comment: I think you are right. Another solution would be to restrict to graphs with at least one edge.